# React Router not working in simple app, showing blank page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am quite new with React and l am trying to do a simple React app. 
I created my project using create-react-app.
But I am having problem implementing Router. 
This is my index.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';

class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <ul>
               <li>Home</li>
               <li>About</li>
               <li>Contact</li>
            </ul>

            {this.props.children}

         </div>
      );
   }
}

class Home extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <h1>Home...</h1>
         </div>
      );
   }
}

class About extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <h1>About...</h1>
         </div>
      );
   }
}

class Contact extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <h1>Contact...</h1>
         </div>
      );
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute path="home" component={Home}/>
        <Route path="about" component={About}/>
        <Route path="contact" component={Contact}/>
      </Route>
   </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

When I run my app, it shows me a blank page, without giving me any error/warning, like in this image:

[React app blank Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNcPa.png)

I understood the simple use of react-router, but I am still not able to understand what is wrong with my code. Any ideas? Thanks for your answers

Comment: Are you using React Router v4? If so you should use their new [react-router-dom](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-dom) package.

Comment: Yes I am using it. Do you suggest to remove react-router package and install react-router-dom package instead?

Comment: I believe that is what you'll have to do. Check out [this official guide](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/guides/quick-start.md#installation), which is pretty much exactly what you are trying to do. v4 introduces some breaking changes.

Comment: Thanks. That actually fixed my issue! l will use react-router-dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Fabian Schultz suggested, since I am using react-router 4.0.0, I should use react-router-dom package instead. This fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the path property in the IndexRoute component because it is relative to its parent. I am writing a simple and clean React boilerplate, you can check it in my [Github](https://github.com/rhberro/the-react-client) page.

To solve your problem you can replace this `<IndexRoute path="home" component={Home}/>` by this `<IndexRoute component={Home}/>`.

In this case the IndexRoute will use the parent path which is "/".

One more thing, I recommend you to use the component `<Link />` instead of default anchor. This way you can easily set an active class to your links. Check it out.

```
import { IndexLink, Link } from 'react-router';

class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <ul>
               <IndexLink to='/' className='anchor' activeClassName='anchor--active'>Home</Link></li>
               <Link to="/about" className='anchor' activeClassName='anchor--active'>About</Link></li>
               <Link to="/contact" className='anchor' activeClassName='anchor--active'>Contact</Link></li>
            </ul>

            {this.props.children}

         </div>
      );
   }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But unfortunately that does not seem to be the problem. I did as you suggested but it s still showing me a blank page.

Comment: Can you tell me which version of React Router are you using?

Comment: I am using version 4.0.0

Comment: The React Router 4.0.0 does not allow you to use template components this way. There is a lot of changes and I recommend you to check the [official documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start).